# BD2: SQL _CASE with group by

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following tables

```
---SALARY_ITEMS---
PERSONID  | EMPLOYMENT _REF | GROUP1  | CODE |   FROM   |    END    | QUANTI
000101        XYX              400      11101 2020-02-12  2020-02-12    12
000101        XYX              300      1100  2020-01-29  2020-02-29    1
000102        XYY              450      11111 2020-02-01  2020-02-12    19
000102        XYY              400      11101 2020-02-02  2020-02-12    82
000103        XYA              500      1100  2020-02-10  2020-02-12    11
000104        XYB              700      1100  2020-01-12  2020-02-12    24 
---PERSON ---
PERSONID    NAME 
000101      Carolina
000102      Helen
000103      Jack
000104      Anna
---EMPLOYMENT---
PERSONID   EMPLOYMENT _REF    POSITION
000101           XYX          doctor
000102           XYY          nurse
000103           XYA          nurse
000104           XYB          Proffesor
----absent---
PERSONID     CODE2   FROM             END
000101        123   2020-03-01       2020-06-30
000102        120   2020-02-05       2020-02-13
000102        123   2020-03-01       2020-03-28
000103        115   2020-05-05       2020-06-30
000104        123   2020-02-01       2020-05-30
```

What I tried to do: get all employee that they are doctor and nurse and have certain group with certain code and works over 100 hours in a 2020 -Feb.

The following SQL query give me what i want  But i want to add something to my query that is :

create a new column to see if the employee was absent in the same period 2020-feb with absent code 120 or 119 or both.

If he was I will get the 'CODE2'  ELSE 'NOTHING'.

How can I do this in DB2?

This is the result I need to get:

```
PERSONID  | NAME | POSITION | QUANTITY |ABSENT (this what i want to have)
000102      Helen   NURSE       101       120
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    S.PERSONID, P.NAME,E.POSTION , sum(S.QUANTITY) as QUANTITY
FROM 
    SALARY_ITEMS  S  
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSON P ON S.PERSONID = P.PERSONID
LEFT JOIN  
    EMPLOYMENT E ON E.EMPLOYMENT_REF = S.EMPLOYMENT _REF
WHERE
    S.group1 IN ('400', '440', '450', '470', '640') 
    AND S.code IN ('11101', '11111', '11121', '11131', '11141')
    AND S.from >= '2020-02-01'
    AND S.end <= '2020-02-29'
    AND E.POSTION IN ('nurse', 'doctor')
    AND (SELECT SUM(S2.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY2
         FROM SALARY_ITEMS S2   
         WHERE S2.group1 IN ('400', '440', '450', '470', '640')
           AND S2.code IN ('11101', '11111', '11121', '11131', '11141')
           AND S2.from >= '2020-02-01'
           AND S2.end <= '2020-02-29'
           AND S.PERSONID = S2.PERSONID) >= '100'
GROUP BY  
    S.PERSONID, P.NAME, E.POSTION
```

Comment: Does this query actually run as written? It looks like `S.PERIOD` is in the `SELECT` clause, but missing from the `GROUP BY` clause...

Comment: @3N1GM4  it work but i delete many lines of it to make it easier to understand  because i asked before with my query and i get it is complex  to understand . so you have right i will fix it now

Comment: You should probably check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then rewrite your question if you want to get good answers.

Comment: Simplify even more. And show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Make it easy to assist you; [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh  i fixed it with table data example

Comment: `SELECT B.*, NVL2 (A.PERSONID, 'CODE2', 'NOTHING') FROM (YOUR_BIG_SELECT) B LEFT JOIN ABSENT A ON B.PERSONID = A.PERSONID AND A.from >= '2020-02-01'
 AND A.end <= '2020-02-29' AND A.CODE2 IN (120, 119)`. Never use string constants in comparisons to numeric data types. `LEFT JOIN EMPLOYMENT E` with references to `E` columns in the `WHERE` clause converts `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, so, use `INNER JOIN` explicitly.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein exact this  what i want thank you very much